# Как организовать скрипт "откуда и куда"?

Tags: алгоритм

Сначала выбираем первый пункт "Откуда" (остановка городского транспорта), далее выбираем "Куда" (тоже остановка городского транспорта), и скрипт показывает все возможные маршруты, на которых можно до этого пункта добраться (трамваи, троллейбусы, маршрутные такси...). И еще показывает примечание, в котором указаны маршруты, на которых можно добраться с пересадками.

Как организовать базу данных и выборку транспорта?

Comment: @pligin то есть вы предлагаете написать за вас?

Comment: @pligin Вы своим апдейтом убили весь интерес вопроса :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Можно обойтись *любой стратегией поиска* на графе, составленном из остановок и маршрутов (добавляя, например, фиктивные ребра на пересадки и на дорогу пешком).

---

В зависимости от масштабов проекта и желаемого результата могу предложить вам следующие варианты:

> - Поиск с помощью **одно- и двунаправленного алгоритма
>     Дейкстры** *(часто слабо не подходит для
>     `production'a`, поскольку требует
>     обхода большого числа ненужных
>     вершин).*
>
> [image]
>
> - Поиск с **помощью одно- и двунаправленного алгоритма `A*`** (или
>     его вариаций типа `Theta*`). Обычно
>     представляет собой лучшее решение для
>     `production'a` по соотношению скорость
>     / сложность реализации. *Нужно твикать
>     эвристику.*
>
> [image]
>
> - Решения промышленного масштаба **с препроцессингом**, позволяющие находить
>     ответ за миллисекунды. Рекомендую презентации и статьи `Andrew Goldberg`, который провел обзоры наиболее современных алгоритмов и эвристик для данной задачи, известных под аббревиатурами `RE`, `HH`, `CH`, `TN`, `HL`. *Ссылки вы найдете в конце ответа.*
>
> [image]

---

Минус всех предложенных выше алгоритмов заключается в том, что они находят только **один кратчайший путь.**

А что делать, если таких путей нужно несколько *(чтобы пользователь мог выбрать удобный для него)?*

> - Можно использовать `A*` с различными эвристиками *(практичное решение, сочетающее возможность настраивать эвристики с преимуществами исходного алгоритма).*
> - Воспользоваться [**алгоритмом Йена**](http://www.siam.org/meetings/alenex03/Abstracts/jhershberger.pdf) для нахождения `k` кратчайших путей на графе.
> - Использовать любой альтернативный алгоритм поиска `k` кратчайших путей *(обычно они менее известны, нежели алгоритм Йена)*, например, [**вот этот.**](http://www.siam.org/meetings/alenex03/Abstracts/jhershberger.pdf)
> - Лично я не знаю алгоритмов, решающих задачу нахождения k кратчайших путей **с массивным препроцессингом**, однако, я не могу гарантировать, что на данный момент по этой теме нет толковых публикаций.

---

Презентации и дополнительные материалы по теме:

- [**Andrew V. Goldberg - Routing Algorithms and Related Technology**](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/goldberg/skolkovo.pdf)
- [**Andrew V. Goldberg - Hub Labeling Algorithm**](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/goldberg/hub-labels.pdf)
- [**Andrew V. Goldberg - Shortest Paths in Road Networks**](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/goldberg/erice.pdf)
- [**Point-to-Point Shortest Path Algorithms with Preprocessing**](http://www.compsciclub.ru/sites/default/files/slides/20080601_ppsp_goldberg.pdf)

Comment: По верстке и объему сразу догадался об авторе ответа )

Comment: > По верстке и объему сразу догадался об авторе ответа )
вы тоже? :) человек форматирует в одинаковом стиле даже ответы. неповерю если кто-то скажет, что у него хаос в форматировании кода :)

Answer (score 3):

Заведите себе гиперграф. Остановки - вершины, маршруты - ребра. Потом ищите пути между вершинами (поиском в ширину, например).